# About Serialization in Hadoop: what are the advantages of serialization?

Tags: java, serialization, hadoop, mapreduce

I am a little confused about serialization in Hadoop data stream. Assume that I have a Java object defined as follows (the object can be much more complex than I have shown):

```
public void MyObject {

  private int Field1;
  private String Field2;

  public void method1() {

  }

  ...

}
```

To transmit instances of this object between mappers and reducers, there are two approaches:

1st approach - I can serialize the int field and String field one by one in mapper and write them to output, and then in reducers, I read them and create a new instance of `MyObject` using these values. Assume that the new-created instance is no difference compared to the original one.

2nd approach- I can rewrite `MyObject` to implement `Writable` interface, and serialize the whole instance in mappers. Then in reducers, I only need to deserialize the object and I can use it.

What is the difference between these two approaches? What are the advantages of serializing an object before transmit it.

Comment: This looks same as your other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16836607/what-are-the-connections-and-differences-between-hadoop-writable-and-java-io-ser/16838260#16838260

Comment: @Tariq I ask this first, and then I asked a more specific question. But actually they are different.

Comment: I didn't notice the time. Please don't mind. And I have said it 'looks same' and not 'the same'.

Comment: @Tariq Thanks for noticing. :-) Can you answer this?

Comment: The first part of your question is covered in the other question. And for the second part, serializing an object before transmitting it makes it more network friendly while transmission and consumes less space, provides better random access and gives you higher performance..

Answer (score 1):

Hadoop `Writable` is more compact and requires less space as compared to Java serializables. Hadoop mapper and reducers deal with objects that extend Hadoops' `Writable` interface. For more details, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/16839597/1150329

Comment: @Denzel please upvote & accept the answer if u r satisfied with it