# Use of readFields() in writable class in hadoop.io api

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, writable

I am new to map-reduce. I want to know what is the use of readfields and write methods when we implement our custom data types in hadoop? For example,

```
     public class Point3D implements Writable {
     public float x;
     public float y;
     public float z;

  public Point3D(float x, float y, float z) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.z = z;
  }

  public Point3D() {
    this(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
  }

  public void write(DataOutput out) throws IOException {
    out.writeFloat(x);
    out.writeFloat(y);
    out.writeFloat(z);
  }

  public void readFields(DataInput in) throws IOException {
    x = in.readFloat();
    y = in.readFloat();
    z = in.readFloat();
  }

  public String toString() {
    return Float.toString(x) + ", "
    + Float.toString(y) + ", "
    + Float.toString(z);
  }
  public void set(float x, float y, float z)
 {
 this.x=x;
 this.y=y;
 this.z=z;
 }
}
```

In the above example the custom recordreader uses the set method to set the values of x, y and z. So we finally, we get these values in the mapper. But whats the need of readfealds and write() methods from writable??
Pls. Help

Answer (score 1):

readFileds() and write() methods are used to read and write serialized data for transferring across the network.

following question explains the need for writables.

[What is the reason for having Writable wrapper classes in Hadoop MapReduce for Java types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17203661/what-is-the-reason-for-having-writable-wrapper-classes-in-hadoop-mapreduce-for-j)